# How it automatically represent state object as parameter in React js?

Tags: reactjs, parameters, setstate

```
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
       super();
       this.state={
           count: 0
       }; 
       this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    
    handleClick(){
        this.setState((e)=>{
            return ({count: e.count + 1})
        })
        
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h2>{this.state.count}</h2>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is a simple React Class Component. My question is in `handleClick()` function I have used `setState()` method. I'm passing arrow function to `setState()` function. In that arrow function I have chosen `e` as parameter. Also I saw that `e` represent *state object* of this class. But I didn't pass that state object. But automatically `e` represent my State object. But I didn't pass state object as parameter in anywhere. How it happen? What is the thing behind that?

Can anyone explain this? I'm a beginner to React.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you are not passing state to `setState`, but what you are passing to `setState` is a function, which then react calls and pass previous state, that is why `e` holds an object which is previous state.

why do you think in the below example `e` will be 5

```
function passFive(funArg) { return funArg(5) }

passFive((e) => console.log(e))
```

Comment: Thank You so much for the information. Its because we have `passFive()` function and it has `funcArg` parameter. Also it returns `funcArg(5)`. It means when we call `passFive` it provide 5 as a parameter. So e represent that value.That's why e will be 5. Thank You so much. Now I got it and this is great explanation Adi.

Answer (score 1):

As a React beginner, I would spend more time on learning [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) which is a different way of working than working with classes. There are many benefits to React Hooks and this is the way that React is developing from here on. At this point, React Class components are still valid, however they are the older way of doing things and are being used less and less.

Here is the new way of doing the same thing that you are looking at, but using React Hooks:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much for the information. I'll check out.